# Set base path with IWebHost in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I have a .NET Core 3.1 web project that includes a background service, and I am hosting the project as a Windows service.

Currently I am having the following Program.cs file

```
 public class Program
 {
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         var host = BuildWebHost(args);

         if (Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--debug"))
         {
             host.Run();
         }
         else
         {
             host.RunAsService();
         }
     }

     public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
     {
         return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
             .UseStartup<Startup>()
             .Build();
     }
 }
```

It works fine but I want to know if there's a way to set a base path so that it uses that path instead of "C:\Windows\System32". Something that we can do with HostBuilder

```
 .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
             {
                 var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule!.FileName;
                 var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);
                 config.SetBasePath(dir);
             })
```

I wanted to use HostBuilder but because I am using Aspnet boilerplate, I was unable to configure it properly and was getting service resolution errors when I was trying to use Startup file with HostBuilder.
Or if someone can help me using HostBuilder along with Aspnet boilerplate, that would work as well.

Here is my startup file for reference:

```
 public class Startup
 {
     public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
         services.AddControllers();
         services.AddHostedService<ProductBackgroundService>();

         var configFilepath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "log4net.config");
         return services.AddAbp<ProductModule>(
             options => options.IocManager.IocContainer.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(
                 f => f.UseAbpLog4Net().WithConfig(configFilepath)
             )
         );
     }

     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
     {
         app.UseAbp(options => { options.UseAbpRequestLocalization = false; });
     }
 }
```

and finally the ProductModule:

```
 [DependsOn(
       typeof(ApplicationModule),
       typeof(EntityFrameworkModule),
       typeof(AbpAspNetCoreModule),
       typeof(AbpAspNetCoreSignalRModule)
   )]
 public class ProductModule : AbpModule
 {
     private readonly IConfigurationRoot _appConfiguration;

     public EMMSubscriberModule(IWebHostEnvironment env)
     {
         _appConfiguration = AppConfigurations.Get(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), env.EnvironmentName, env.IsDevelopment());
     }

     public override void PreInitialize()
     {
         Configuration.DefaultNameOrConnectionString = _appConfiguration.GetConnectionString(
             Consts.ConnectionStringName
         );
         _appConfiguration.Bind("Services:Queue", Configuration.Modules.InfrastructureQueueModule());
         _appConfiguration.Bind("Services:ProductAPI", Configuration.Modules.InfrastructureProductModule());
     }

     public override void Initialize()
     {
         IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(typeof(ProductModule).GetAssembly());
     }

     public override void PostInitialize()
     {
         IocManager.Resolve<ApplicationPartManager>()
            .AddApplicationPartsIfNotAddedBefore(typeof(ProductModule).Assembly);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = BuildWebHost(args);

        if (Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--debug"))
        {
            host.Run();
        }
        else
        {
            host.RunAsService();
        }
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
        var baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseContentRoot(baseDirectory) // Set the base path
            .Build();

        return host;
    }
}
```

Just set the base bath like this.
Hope it helps!